# "OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException: 'Timed out after 40 seconds'

Tags: c#, selenium

I'm trying to Code in Selenuim with C# for a website, after `Username` it's getting time out with the message

> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException: 'Timed out after 40 seconds'

Here is my code which I'm referring to.

```
  //Enter user info
  SetMethods.EnterText(driver, "Username", "svedanth", "ID");
  SetMethods.EnterText(driver, "Password", "openopen", "ID");

  SetMethods.Click(driver, "Next", "ID");

  //Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
  wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(
  By.XPath(".//*[@id='logOnContainer']/form/div[1]/button")));
```

Comment: Give us your HTML code.

Comment: It's because ALL elements found by that locator are not visible after 40 seconds. What's the question?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new WebDriverWait like so:

```
WebDriverWait customWait = new WebDriverWait(driver,TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
```

and do

```
customWait.Until(ExpectedConditions.VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.XPath(".//*[@id='logOnContainer']/form/div[1]/button")));
```

when you initialized your wait at some point in your code, you probably set the timeout at 40 seconds.

The reason you have your problem, is because 40 seconds pass and your elements are still not visible. After they are all visible, program stop "waiting" and will continue with the rest of the code.

If you will, you can set your own timeout by changing the TimeSpan I gave in my example.