# Selenium test fails to run with IE11 on build machine running TFS 2018 build agent

Tags: c#, selenium, internet-explorer, tfs

I've been trying for a while now to get selenium tests working with IE 11 on our build machine. Our build machine runs Windows 10 with IE11 and we use TFS 2018. The build agent is configured to run interactively with auto-logon. My test runs on my local machine with IE, Chrome and Firefox. Chrome and Firefox also work on the build machine, just IE I can't get to work. I've added the registry entries and checked all other settings according to the following documentation:

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver

The test I'm running is just a basic sample.

```
[TestClass]
public class MySeleniumTests
{
    private TestContext testContextInstance;
    private IWebDriver driver;
    private string appURL;

    public MySeleniumTests()
    {
    }

    [TestMethod]
    [TestCategory("Chrome")]
    public void TheBingSearchTest()
    {
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(appURL);
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("sb_form_q")).SendKeys("VSTS");
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("sb_form_go")).Click();
        driver.FindElement(By.XPath("(//ol[@id='b_results']/li/h2/a/strong)[3]")).Click();
        Assert.IsTrue(driver.Title.Contains("VSTS"), "Verified title of the page");
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///Gets or sets the test context which provides
    ///information about and functionality for the current test run.
    ///</summary>
    public TestContext TestContext
    {
        get
        {
            return testContextInstance;
        }
        set
        {
            testContextInstance = value;
        }
    }

    [TestInitialize()]
    public void SetupTest()
    {
        appURL = "http://www.bing.com/";

        string browser = TestContext.Properties["browser"].ToString();
        switch (browser)
        {
            case "Chrome":
                driver = new ChromeDriver();
                break;
            case "Firefox":
                driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                break;
            case "IE":
                driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
                break;
            default:
                driver = new ChromeDriver();
                break;
        }

    }

    [TestCleanup()]
    public void MyTestCleanup()
    {
        driver.Quit();
    }
}
```

The browser instance starts every time with the correct website but then fails to continue with the following error:

```
2018-03-14T20:53:53.1180620Z Started InternetExplorerDriver server (32-bit)
2018-03-14T20:53:53.1180620Z 3.11.0.0
2018-03-14T20:53:53.1180620Z Listening on port 53215
2018-03-14T20:53:53.1180620Z Only local connections are allowed
2018-03-14T20:53:54.8474473Z Failed   TheBingSearchTest
2018-03-14T20:53:54.8474473Z Error Message:
2018-03-14T20:53:54.8474473Z  Test method Web.Tests.MySeleniumTests.TheBingSearchTest threw exception: 
2018-03-14T20:53:54.8474473Z OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with css selector == #sb_form_q
2018-03-14T20:53:54.8474473Z Stack Trace:
2018-03-14T20:53:54.8474473Z     at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
2018-03-14T20:53:54.8474473Z    at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
2018-03-14T20:53:54.8474473Z    at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(String mechanism, String value)
2018-03-14T20:53:54.8474473Z    at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElementById(String id)
2018-03-14T20:53:54.8474473Z    at OpenQA.Selenium.By.<>c__DisplayClass16_0.<Id>b__0(ISearchContext context)
2018-03-14T20:53:54.8474473Z    at OpenQA.Selenium.By.FindElement(ISearchContext context)
2018-03-14T20:53:54.8474473Z    at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(By by)
2018-03-14T20:53:54.8474473Z    at Web.Tests.MySeleniumTests.TheBingSearchTest() in E:\BuildAgents\BuildAgent1\_work\16\s\Web.Tests\SeleniumBingTest.cs:line 29
2018-03-14T20:53:54.8474473Z
```

I've been checking everything multiple times now and been also trying different things but I'm not making any progress. Has anyone else been having similar issues?

--- edit 03/15 ---

After adding the delay as suggested by DebanjanB I'm getting now the following exception. It says the window was closed but it is actually still open. The behavior is so weird. I believe I'm missing some infrastructure config, something related to the TFS test agent running the test, but I can't figure out what it could be.

```
2018-03-15T14:20:21.5983187Z Starting test execution, please wait...
2018-03-15T14:20:22.5350340Z Started InternetExplorerDriver server (32-bit)
2018-03-15T14:20:22.5350340Z 3.9.0.0
2018-03-15T14:20:22.5350340Z Listening on port 63267
2018-03-15T14:20:22.5350340Z Only local connections are allowed
2018-03-15T14:20:23.2691823Z Skipped  LoginFirstTimeTest
2018-03-15T14:20:54.6453061Z Failed   TheBingSearchTest
2018-03-15T14:20:54.6453061Z Error Message:
2018-03-15T14:20:54.6453061Z  Test method Web.Tests.MySeleniumTests.TheBingSearchTest threw exception: 
2018-03-15T14:20:54.6453061Z OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException: Timed out after 30 seconds ---> OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Currently focused window has been closed.
2018-03-15T14:20:54.6453061Z Stack Trace:
2018-03-15T14:20:54.6453061Z     at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
2018-03-15T14:20:54.6453061Z    at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
2018-03-15T14:20:54.6453061Z    at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(String mechanism, String value)
2018-03-15T14:20:54.6453061Z    at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElementById(String id)
2018-03-15T14:20:54.6453061Z    at OpenQA.Selenium.By.<>c__DisplayClass16_0.<Id>b__0(ISearchContext context)
2018-03-15T14:20:54.6453061Z    at OpenQA.Selenium.By.FindElement(ISearchContext context)
2018-03-15T14:20:54.6453061Z    at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(By by)
2018-03-15T14:20:54.6453061Z    at SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.<>c__DisplayClass19_0.<ElementToBeClickable>b__0(IWebDriver driver)
2018-03-15T14:20:54.6453061Z    at OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.DefaultWait`1.Until[TResult](Func`2 condition)
2018-03-15T14:20:54.6453061Z --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2018-03-15T14:20:54.6453061Z     at OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.DefaultWait`1.ThrowTimeoutException(String exceptionMessage, Exception lastException)
2018-03-15T14:20:54.6453061Z    at OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.DefaultWait`1.Until[TResult](Func`2 condition)
2018-03-15T14:20:54.6453061Z    at Web.Tests.MySeleniumTests.TheBingSearchTest() in E:\BuildAgents\BuildAgent1\_work\16\s\Web.Tests\SeleniumBingTest.cs:line 31
2018-03-15T14:20:54.6453061Z
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says it all :

```
2018-03-14T20:53:54.8474473Z  Test method Web.Tests.MySeleniumTests.TheBingSearchTest threw exception: 
2018-03-14T20:53:54.8474473Z OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with css selector == #sb_form_q
```

It is clear from the error stack trace that the *driver* is unable to locate the element identified as :

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("sb_form_q"))
```

As you mentioned, *test runs on your local machine with IE, Chrome and Firefox. Chrome and Firefox also work on the build machine, just IE  can't get to work* may happen as different *Web Browsers* renders the *HTML DOM* differently.

### Solution

A solution would be to induce [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_WebDriverWait.htm) with [ExpectedConditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions.htm) clause [ElementToBeClickable](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions_ElementToBeClickable.htm) as follows :

```
wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Id("sb_form_q"))).SendKeys("VSTS");
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I of course saw the error message, but that doesn't explain to me why it would behave differently on two machines with the exact same setup. Both Windows 10 with IE11 (exact same version). It works on my local machine but not on the build machine. I give the delay a try but that just seems a little messy to me. But I'm also new to selenium so maybe that's just how it's done then. Thanks, I'll let you know the outcome.

Comment: I have edited my initial post. The behavior just seems completely different. As soon as the browser instance is fired up it seems to lose focus.

Comment: Of-coarse there seems to be something else wrong happening in your script as per the log `OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException: Timed out after 30 seconds ---> OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Currently focused window has been closed.` which you need to debug next.

Comment: Thank you, I do understand how stackoverflow works. However your answer did not solve my problem. The test still does not run through, now I'm just getting a different exception which the cause for it is probably in both cases the same. The browser window opens and then loses focus why it can't find the input field. What I'm trying to solve is WHY that happens, and that's probably related to the agent running the test.

Comment: @5earch Just try to create a new WebDriverWait, refer to this thread for details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47102759/openqa-selenium-webdrivertimeoutexception-timed-out-after-40-seconds